# can someone tell me how to count the select prepare statement returns?

Tags: php, mysqli

The problem is, I have a statement like this one below and i use it in server side of my android app

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ? OR username = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $email, $username);
$result = mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
$rows = mysqli_stmt_fetch($result);
```

And I want to know how many rows are back from it so I can know if there is already data in the database with the same username and email or not, but it doesn't work.

How to solve this problem? And thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: yes but i cant understand i just want a way to know how mych rows are returned

Comment: Why is this tagged android?

Comment: Take a look at : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.num-rows.php

Comment: i will remove android tag my mistake

Comment: ok i will check the link tosee if i can understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And I want to know how many rows are back

Nope, you don't. That's a false goal.

When working with a database, you should **always request the exact data you need**, instead of doing some calculations on the client side.

So in your case you need the user info - so select that info. Means this very user info you can use to tell whether your query returned anything or not.

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ? OR username = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $email, $username);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
$result = mysqli_get_result($statement);
$user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

//now you have the very $user variable to tell whether anything was found
if ($user) {
  //user exists
}
```

Answer (score -1):

All you are missing is to use the `num_rows` function with the resulting mysqli object:

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, 
    "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ? OR username = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $email, $username);
$result = mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$numbRows = $result->num_rows;

//printing the result:
echo "number of rows = {$numbRows}<br>";
```

Comment: no because i found a new problem :( thats annoying .. but your solution is still with me :D

Comment: @AhmedNader I see. Oh and if my solution worked for the specific problem asked in your question, please accept it with a green checkmark so that future users / readers know

Comment: i solved my other problem .. and yes ofcourse i am trying yours now and if yes i will mark it :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113273/discussion-between-webeng-and-ahmed-nader).

Comment: I posted a few things in the "chat" that is linked

Comment: where is the chat actually :D

Comment: see where I said "Let us continue this discussion in chat."? click on the word "chat"